# JavaFX Clients and JDBC Servers: Are JavaFX Bean-style objects required on the server side?

Tags: java, jdbc, javafx-2

I have a JDBC application that is built around a single-server database (the RDBMS is HSQLDB -- which I love so far).  In my first draft of the application, I have used the following tiered approach:

```
+-------------------------------+ 
|  DATA STORE (appx 20 tables)  |  HSQLDB; highly normalized tables
+-------------------------------+
                |
                v
+-------------------------------+
|  DOMAIN OBJECT LAYER  (1:1)   |  A Java class for each table in DB
+-------------------------------+
                |
                v
+-------------------------------+  Abstraction for the objects that the app
|  CLIENT OBJECT LAYER / DAO's  |  logic actually uses (denormalized)
+-------------------------------+
                |
                V
+-------------------------------+  Adapts ObservableArrayList() instances 
|  PRESENTATION LAYER (JAVAFX)  |  of objects to the GUI
+-------------------------------+
```

In the Domain Object Layer I presently do all JDBC queries with a generic static method:

```
static <E> ObservableList<E> doGenericQuery(SQLParametersList pars,
        String sql, Callback<RowSet,E> factory) {

    // factory is a Function Object. For now I use Callback<P,R> as the
    // "strategy" ... P is a RowSet, R is the object return type. The factory
    // simply invokes the constructor for the desired return object type.


    RowSet jrs = null;
    ObservableList<E> queryList = FXCollections.<E>observableArrayList();

    try {
        jrs = SQLConnection.getRowSetInstance();
        if (jrs == null) {
            System.err.println(Census.MSG_ERR_JDBCFAIL);
            return queryList; }

        jrs.setCommand(sql);

        for(int i=0; i < pars.size(); i++) {

            // datum().col() method returns an enum representing the
            // database column; setJdbcParamByType is an enum 
            // constant-specific method that invokes the correct
            // setXXX method on the PreparedStatement

            pars.datum(i).col().setJdbcParamByType(jrs, pars.datum(i)));
        }

        jrs.execute();

        while (jrs.next()) {
            queryList.add(factory.<RowSet,E>call(jrs));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {            
        Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);

    } finally {            
        if (jrs != null) try { jrs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { }
    }

    return queryList; 
}
```

What I would like to do is use this method in the data access abstraction for my whole application, but I'm wondering if I can.  As written, this method returns an ObservableList because it is used by a JavaFX application.  The ObservableList holds instances of SimpleXXXProperty objects (JavaFX Bean-style, i.e. mutable, objects).  I don't think I can use this code as presently written because I don't want to take JavaFX Bean-style objects to the server-side.

Eventually, the data access layers are going to be executed in a server-side environment and the presentation-layer stuff is going to happen on the client.

I really don't want to have my server-side code using JavaFX Bean-style objects.  Ideally, I want the queries to form a list of immutable objects and I think I could accomplish that except for the necessity to deal with JavaFX which seems to mandate that I make everything public and mutable.

The solution that I am thinking of now is to have the server code create immutable objects from the query result that get wrapped in an unmodifiableList which then gets transmitted to the client.  The client then has to transmogrify the read-only list into an ObservableList of JavaFX Bean-style objects so that they may be used in the GUI.  BUT .. this approach requires that I write different version of my Domain Object Layer (client and server).

Am I on the right track here? (I hate to sound like I'm in over my head, here .. but I may be in over my head right now).

Answer (score 0):

As I've thought more about what it is I'd like to do, I've understood that my approach is far too simplistic.  What I think I'm really talking about is a flow from information from the data store to the client that looks closer to this:

```
+-------------------------------+ 
|  DATA STORE (appx 20 tables)  |  HSQLDB; highly normalized tables
+-------------------------------+
                |
                v
+-------------------------------+  Receives query result
|  SERVER/SERVLET REQ PROCESSOR |  Transmits as CachedRowSet
+-------------------------------+
                |
         (Serialization)
                |
                v
+-------------------------------+
|     CLIENT INTERFACE LAYER    |  Deserializes query results
+-------------------------------+
                |
                v
+-------------------------------+
|  DOMAIN OBJECT LAYER  (1:1)   |  A Java class for each table in DB
+-------------------------------+  Generates data model objects from results
                |
                v
+-------------------------------+  Abstraction for the objects that the app
|  CLIENT OBJECT LAYER / DAO's  |  logic actually uses (denormalized)
+-------------------------------+
                |
                V
+-------------------------------+  Adapts ObservableArrayList() instances 
|  PRESENTATION LAYER (JAVAFX)  |  of objects to the GUI
+-------------------------------+
```

Of course, this is now looking rather more like an internet-based client-server app for which frameworks already exist, eg. JavaEE.  Going from a simple, single-machine JDBC database app to a distributed client-server app appears to involve a quantum leap in complexity.

But, I do not believe that I need to use JavaFX Bean-style objects anywhere in this process at all, except on the client.